# When in JS you need to identify element by array order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

Ok so I finally have a code example to show this!

```
if ($('#Snowsports-row')[0].classList.contains("hidden") == false) {
  $('#snowsports-only').removeClass("hidden")
}
```

The code works ONLY as written above, i.e., if the `[0]` were moved to the second line and removed from the first line, or if it were present/absent in both lines, it would fail.

I understand the output difference...

```
$('#Snowsports-row')
=> [<div>...]
$('#Snowsports-row')[0]
=> <div>...
```

...but I'm not understanding under what circumstances you're OK to get an array of element(s) and in which you need to tease out the exact element.

THANKS FOR ALL ANSWERS! Very clearly helped me to figure out that the problem may have been confusing JS/jQuery methods. Final version:

```
if ($('#Snowsports-row').hasClass("hidden") == false) {
  $('#snowsports-only').removeClass("hidden")
}
```

Comment: _under what circumstances you're OK to get an array of element(s)_.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, by using jQuery for what it's good at, you can replace this:

```
if ($('#Snowsports-row')[0].classList.contains("hidden") == false) {
  $('#snowsports-only').removeClass("hidden")
}
```

with this:

```
$('#Snowsports-row').removeClass("hidden");
```

Your first block of code does the following:

1. With `$('#Snowsports-row')`, make a jQuery object that contains all DOM elements that match the select `'#Snowsports-row'`.
2. Then reach into the jQuery object with `[0]` and get the first DOM object in that jQuery object.
3. Then, use a property/method on that DOM element to determine if a class exists on that DOM element with your `.classList.contains("hidden")` reference.
4. Then, if you find that class, remove it.

A jQuery object contains inside it an array of DOM elements.  If you call a method on the jQuery object itself like:

```
$('.tableRows').html("hello");
```

Then, you are asking jQuery to operate on ALL the DOM elements inside the jQuery object.  You must use jQuery methods, not DOM methods.

If, on the other hand, you want to use a method such as `.classList.contains()`, that is only a method on an actual DOM element.  That isn't a jQuery method.  So, you have to reach inside of the jQuery object to get a specific DOM element out of it.  That's what the `[0]` does.  It reaches into the jQuery object and gets the first DOM element from its internal data structure.  Once you have that DOM element, you can then use any DOM element methods on that DOM object.

---

FYI, if you ever want to get just the first DOM element from a jQuery object, but want the result to be a jQuery object, not just a DOM element, instead of `[0]`, you can use `.eq(0)` like ths:

```
$('#Snowsports-row').eq(0).removeClass("hidden");
```

Now, in this specific case, this is never necessary because `$('#Snowsports-row')` cannot ever contain more than one DOM element because internally jQuery will only return the first matching DOM element when you are searching for a ID value (since there's never supposed to be more than one matching element with the same ID).

---

Just keep in mind that DOM element and a jQuery object are completely different types of objects with different methods on them.  What makes it slightly confusing is that a jQuery object contains an internal list of DOM elements.  But, if the object you are operating on is a jQuery object, then you can only call jQuery methods on it.  If you reach into the jQuery object and pull out a DOM element, then you can only call DOM methods on it.

Comment: the one thing that doesn't add up is, as I noted in my question, if I append [0] to the second line of code, it actually does NOT work, which means I have to `removeClass` from all elements, for whatever reason

Comment: @james - Yes, that's because `.removeClass()` is a jQuery method, NOT a DOM object method.  You must call the right type of method on the right type of object.  When you do `[0]`, you get a DOM object which does NOT have a `.removeClass()` method as that is a jQuery method.

Comment: @james - For more explanation, see what I added to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `.classList` method is not widely supported (not in MSIE 9.0 for example) so it's not portable, although where it exists it's fast.

Since every ID in a document is supposed to be unique, and since calling `removeClass` for a class that isn't present is harmless, just replace your entire call with:

```
$('#Snowsports-row').removeClass('hidden')
```

Or better yet, if that class means what I think it does, use `.hide()` and let jQuery do its job for you, potentially animation the transition in the process.

Alternatively, if you actually wanted to stick with using DOM and `classList`, you should use the `.remove()` method that classList already supports:

```
document.getElementById('#Snowsports-row').classList.remove('hidden')
```

although there's a minor disadvantage in that this code will crash if that element isn't found (since `.getElementById` will return `null`) whereas jQuery silently ignores calls made on empty selectors.

As for the meta-question - you use `[n]` if you want to access the single DOM element at position `n` within the jQuery object, as you've done when you use `.classList`.

You use `.eq(n)` to obtain a jQuery object representing that DOM element, e.g. if you want to apply jQuery methods to that (single) element.

If there's only a single element, or you want the jQuery method to apply to every matching element, just call the method directly on the selector, as I've done above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ids must be unique, so if you have more than one `#Snowsports-only` elements you can experience problems.

In your question, you are mixing jQuery code with pure Javascript code.

This:

```
if ($('#Snowsports-row')[0].classList.contains("hidden") {
  ...
}
```

Means that you get the first instance of `#Snowsports-row` (remember that is better if there is only one element with this id), but you get the DOM object (pure javascript) with the jQuery selector. You can do the same thing in jQuery like this:

```
$('#Snowsports-row').hasClass("hidden")
```

See more:

https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: oh yes `hasClass` was what I was trying to remember, but I couldn't so did a google and the JS version came up first

Answer (score 0):

Sure, because you are operating over a list. Now, you're kind of mistaking the jQuery/javascript code. If you would like to use the same line twice you can basically drop jQuery altogether and write something like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('Snowsports-row');
if (el.classList.contains('hidden')){
  el.classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery's [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) function. So:

```
var el = $('#Snowsports-row').eq(0);
if (el.hasClass("hidden")) {
  $(el.removeClass("hidden")
}
```

There's also no harm in calling `removeClass` on an element that might not have that class... so:

```
$('#Snowsports-row').eq(0).removeClass('hidden');
```

Comment: Sorry, meant `.eq()`. I've changed it.

Answer (score -1):

In the first line you're selecting one specific DOM element, whereas in the second line you are selecting ALL elements in the DOM that fit that selector and removing the "hidden" class from all of them. Basically checking whether the element has a class can only be performed over an element (that's why you need to select the index, specifying a given element), but jQuery allows you to remove the class of every element inside a list (hence your second line)

Comment: ok this explanation  makes a ton of sense... except that as I noted in my question, if I append `[0]` to the second line of code, it actually does NOT work, which means I have to `removeClass` from all elements, for whatever reason

Comment: @james there shouldn't be more than one element matching that selector.

Comment: @james you need to use `.eq()` to select individual jquery elements from the collection instead of `[]`

Comment: Sure, because you are operating over a list. Now, you're kind of mistaking the jQuery/javascript code. If you would like to use the same line twice you can basically drop jQuery altogether and write something like this:
`
var el = document.getElementById('Snowsports-row');
if (el.classList.contains('hidden')){
  el.classList.remove('hidden')
}
`